# Why are <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::CHILD_B)]" /> and <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(CHILD_B)]" /> not the same?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I am currently learning XSLT and a bit confused about an example I found in a book. To select all nodes, except a certain node, it says to use:

`<xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::CHILD_B)]" />`

This works, but I was wondering why the `self::` part is at all needed? Why does `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(CHILD_B)]" />` not work? After all `<xsl:apply-templates select="CHILD_B" />` would work to select the element (without the `self::` part), so why do we need the `self::` part when excluding it?

Examples:

test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>
    <CHILD_A>
        Test A
    </CHILD_A>
    <CHILD_B>
        This element should be ignored.
    </CHILD_B>
    <CHILD_C>
        Test C
    </CHILD_C>  
</ROOT>
```

test.xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="ROOT">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::CHILD_B)]" />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the predicate, the context node is changed to whatever node was selected in the expression on the left side of the predicate so `node()[not(CHILD_B)]` looks for any child node of the context node but then, inside the predicate to be evaluated, this child node is the context node so that `not(CHILD_B)` tests whether the outer child node has no `CHILD_B` child element on its own.

While `node()[not(self::CHILD_B)]` checks whether any selected (outer) child node is not a `CHILD_B` element.